# Exception assertion along with other assertions jUnit

Tags: exception, junit, junit4, junit-rule

I have a method that throws exception. And i have a test like this.

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException expectedEx = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void shouldThrowExceptionIfValidationFails() throws Exception {
    doThrow(new InvalidException("Invalid Token")).when(obj).foo(any());

    expectedEx.expect(InvalidException.class);
    expectedEx.expectMessage("Invalid Token");

    // my method call

    // verify DB save doesn't happens

    assertTrue(false);
}
```

The test assert for exception, and since the exception is thrown the test passes. It doesn't care about the last line `assertTrue(false)`

How can i make sure that my other assertions are also satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

This is the pattern I follow for this case. It uses `ExpectedException` as designed. I like the `throw e` rather than failing after method method call in the `try` because it will not result in a false-positive if someone decides to delete the `fail` (which people have a tendency to do when they see `fail()` or if a test is failing because it hits a `fail()`).

```
@Test
public void shouldThrowExceptionIfValidationFails() throws Exception {
  doThrow(new InvalidException("Invalid Token")).when(obj).foo(any());

   expectedEx.expect(InvalidException.class);
   expectedEx.expectMessage("Invalid Token");

   try{
     // my method call
   }catch(InvalidException e){
     // verify DB save doesn't happens

    assertTrue(false);

    throw e;
  }
 }
```